# Why I need to click on button two times to set props on component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Why `direction` props is only updated after first click/execution and `questionid` not?

Suggestion in #vuejs@freenode is:

> deadbeat: my guess is that the reactive property only gets updated after the
>   direct call to $refs vote, but it is updated the first time

```js
Vue.component('vote-component', {
  template: '<div>{{this.direction}}</div>',
  props: {
    questionid: Number,
    direction: String
  },
  methods: {
    vote() {
      console.log({
        id: this.questionid,
        direction: this.direction
      });
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      direction: '',
      question: {
        id: 10
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    vote(direction) {
      this.direction = direction;
      this.$refs.voteComp.vote();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="vote('UP')">Y</button>
  <vote-component ref="voteComp" :direction="direction" :questionid="question.id" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the scheduler for Vue watcher](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/scheduler.js#L153), the reactivy of the props='direction' with type=String is triggered at current task. But the value of `direction` will be updated at next render cycle (actually next [event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops), you can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) for better understanding) (Vue calls `nextTick(vueQueue)`, something is similar with `setTimeout(()=>{this.direction=newValue}, 0)`).

Below is one demo:

You will see I added one Promise at `App.vote`. `the callback of Promise.then` is [micro task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Timing) will be executed directly after current task finishes before next render cycle.

Then you will see `console.log('watch', newVal, oldVal)` will be executed after Promise.then.

Also I put one setTimeout at there before `this.direction=direction`, you will see it will be executed after `this.$refs.voteComp.vote()` but before `console.log('watch', newVal, oldVal)` because it is older task in [the event loop -> task queue](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops).

And for `prop=questionid`, it will be same.

```js
Vue.component('vote-component', {
  template: '<div>{{questionid}}: {{this.direction}}</div>',
  props: {
    questionid: Number,
    direction: String
  },
  watch: {
    direction: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('**watch**', newVal, oldVal)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    vote() {
      console.log({
        id: this.questionid,
        direction: this.direction
      });
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      direction: '',
      question: {
        id: 10
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    vote(direction) {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('the handler at setTimeout Executed')
      }, 0)
      this.direction = direction
      this.question.id = 7
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('update direction in root')
        resolve()
      }).then(()=>{
        console.log('micro task executed')
      })
      
      this.$refs.voteComp.vote();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="vote('UP')">Y</button>
  <vote-component ref="voteComp" :direction="direction" :questionid="question.id" />
</div>
```